# Laravel-5 adding hasRole method to Auth

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to extend the Laravel-5.1 `Auth` middleware so that I can add my own method to it:

`Auth::hasRole()`

What do I need to do in order to add the new method hasRole to Auth?

Here is my routes file:

```
/* Administrator Routes */

Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware' => 'timesheets.admin:Administrator'], function()
{
    Route::get('home', 'AdminController@index');
});
```

Here is my middleware file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware\Auth;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class AdminAuthenticate
{
    /**
     * The Guard implementation.
     *
     * @var Guard
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new filter instance.
     *
     * @param  Guard  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
    {
        if ($this->auth->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('login');
            }
        }

        if (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->hasRole($role)) {
            return $next($request);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If you want it part of the Auth class and not the User model, you'll have to extend the Auth class.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Could you try adding the following to your User model:-

```
public function hasRole($role)
{
    return User::where('role', $role)->get();
}
```

This should firstly check to see if you User table has the field 'role' and then check your parameter `$role` against the `role` field.

You can the check by doing the following:

```
if( Auth::user()->hasRole($role) )
```

You may need to adjust the example to your needs. Let me know if you need anything else.

/------------EDIT-----------------/

If you have two seperate tables, one holding the user information and the other holding the users privileges/roles you could add another function to the User model:

```
public function userID()
{
    return $this->user_id; 
}
```

This will check for if you have a user ID field if so, it will return the id for the authenticated user.

Then add this to your `hasRoles` method:

```
    public function hasRoles($userID, $roles)
{
    return Your\User\Roles\Model::where('role', $role)->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
}
```

Your middleware would look like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
{
    if ($this->auth->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('login');
        }
    }

    $userID = Auth::user()->userID();

    if (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->hasRole($userID, $role)) {
        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

If I understood correctly what you want. I believe this should work for you.

Comment: I agree that this should be part of the User model.

Comment: one more query? role is a field?

Comment: Sorry guys, I should have told you this in my original post.  `role` is not a field in my users table.  User roles are stored in a separate table.

Comment: Is there a way to link your table which holds roles to your users table?

Comment: @jakehallas yes the roles are linked to the `users` table by the `users_roles` table and the user_id column.

Comment: You're a star!  I managed to implement it perfect using the above :)  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I've taken a different tack by using a trait in my `User` model.

```
<?php
namespace App\Traits;

use App\Role;
use App\User;

trait HasRoles{
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }

    public static function findByRole(Role $role)
    {
        return $role->users()->get();
    }

    public function hasRole(Role $role)
    {
        return $this->roles()->get()->contains($role);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some good packages to help with this if you don't want to brew your own. I can recommend both:
Zizaco Entrust: https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust
and
Sentinel: https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0