# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::role()

Tags: php, laravel

I get this error in my view when i tried to check whether the user has some role. The exact error is 
**Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::role() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-projects\acl\resources\views\admin.blade.php**

Here is the admin.blade.php code

```
@foreach($users as $user)
<tr>

<td>{{$user->name}}</td>
<td>{{$user->email}}</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" {{ $user->hasRole('User') ? 'checked' : '' }} name="role_user"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" {{ $user->hasRole('Author') ? 'checked' : '' }} name="role_author"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" {{ $user->hasRole('Admin') ? 'checked' : '' }} name="role_admin"></td>
<td>{{$user->name}}</td>
<td>{{$user->email}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

**hasRole()** is a function in the user model. But from the error it throws undefined methode role(). But there is no method called role()

Here is my controller

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{

public function index()
{   
$user_details = User::all();
return view('admin')->with('users' , $user_details);
}    
}
```

I also did include the method while getting the data from DB like

```
$user_details = User::with('hasRole')->get();
```

Even this didn't work.

This is my User model.

```
<?php

namespace App;
use App\Role;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{

public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role','user_role','user_id','role_id');
}

public function hasAnyRole($roles)
{
    if(is_array($roles)){

        foreach ($roles as $role) {

            if ($this->hasRole($role)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    else{

        if ($this->hasRole($roles)) {

            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function hasRole($role)
{
    if ($this->role()->where('name',$role)->first()) {

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790234/laravel-5-adding-hasrole-method-to-auth

Answer (score 4):

You have `roles()` relation, but you're trying to call `role()`. That's why you're getting the error.

So, change code to this:

```
 if ($this->roles()->where('name',$role)->first()) {
```

Comment: Seriously i didnt notice that. Thank you so much :D